# Smaller Edge Sizes in Sigma V2

Tags: sigma.js

In Sigma v1 (webgl) I am able to render edge sizes at "0.01". In v2 I am unable to render edges any smaller than "1".

I have tried modifying different values in the default edge program, but not exactly sure what I'm doing in there.

[This is how the graph renders in v2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRHhN.jpg)

[This is how the graph renders in v1 with edge sizes set to 0.01.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZpGe.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities :

1. put the `size` attribute at `0.1` on every edges in the graph

```
graph.edges().forEach(key => {
  graph.setEdgeAttribute(key, 'size', 0.1);
})
```

2. Passing an edgeRudecer in the sigma settings that set the `size` attribut :

```
edgeReducer: (edge, data) => {
  return {...data, size:0.1 }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these options worked. Anything under "size: 1", does not make a difference.

Comment: which edge program are you using ?

Comment: It works on this example : https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-rubin-6k4e0?file=/index.ts

Comment: the default program

Comment: so without more info, I can't help you. Like I said, it works on the example I gave. did you try it ?